# Is it really beneficial to put papaya seeds in the sun for a few minutes before planting?

Tags: seeds, planting, sunlight, tropical, papaya

My friend tells me I should place papaya seeds in direct sunlight for about 20 minutes just before putting them into the soil. She says this will be beneficial to germination, among other things.

Is there any truth to this, or is it just a myth?

Answer (score 4):

Some people dry them in the sun for a couple of days to help remove the (germination inhibiting) aril but if you can remove it in other ways that's fine.

The idea is to get a clean seed into warm soil, that doesn't stay moist as their roots rot easily.  They can take a month to germinate, so perhaps leaving it out just before planting might help trigger germination if your soil is not at ideal temperature but it seems unlikely.